# scrollbar in main div to display divs within it

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am building a site that is only 640px wide and I have a div that I want to float a number of divs and have a scroll bar appear below so the user can scroll left to right to view the different divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/nNG64/1/

html

```
<div id="all-videos">
  <div class="video-item">Video one</div>
  <div class="video-item">Video two</div>
  <div class="video-item">Video three</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#all-videos {
  width: 640px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border:1px solid red;
  background: #000;
}

.video-item {
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 280px; 
}
```

The one time I want to display a scrollbar that goes horizontal, I can't, but when I don't want one...it finds itself in there to be debugged :)

Attached is a screenshot of the proof, I'll have to style the scrollbar but that shouldn't be a problem, I just need to get this to work.

[image]

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/nNG64/6/ If yes I will answer the question

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `overflow-x:scroll` and `overflow-y:hidden` for `#all-videos`
2. Wrap the videos inside `#all-videos` with something that has a width greater than `#all-videos`, otherwise the content will break to the next line:

html

```
<div id="all-videos">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="video-item">Video one</div>
        <div class="video-item">Video two</div>
        <div class="video-item">Video three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#all-videos {
width: 640px;
height: 300px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
border:1px solid red;
background: #000;
}
.video-wrapper {
width:1626px;
}
.video-item {
float: left;
background: #eee;
border:1px solid #000;
width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
height: 280px; 
}
```